# Named Pipe communication over LAN slow response if not used for a while

Tags: named-pipes

Our client PCs have a continuous loop running with a NamedPipe listener waiting for connection.  Our server sends a command to the remote PC's as needed.  The first connection takes a long time, around 10 seconds.  The following connections are very fast, about 1 second.  If another communication is not made in less than approximately 10 minutes, it takes another approximately 10 seconds to reestablish connection through the Named Pipe.

My question: Is there a setting on our server or our client PC's that would reduce or eliminate the long wait if the connection has not been used for over 10 minutes (approx.)

It's also possible that Named Pipe communication is not the way to go for us.  Ultimately, we need a way to send a small string to a listening program on the remote PC's very quickly at any time.  Other suggestions are welcome also.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: How are you authenticating? Domain credentials? I would bet the time is spent in contacting the domain controller to validate the credentials. Perhaps a DNS resolution problem.

Comment: Yes it is using Domain credentials.  We have child DNS servers in all of our branch offices (I believe).  The delay happens locally as well.  If the DNS servers refresh, could this potentially cause the delay?  Thanks!